# how to get a month name from a number

Tags: java

I need a code that can takes a number as an input and tells month and date of the month as output. For example,

USer input: 33
Output: February 2

Can someone help me understand the logic to this problem.

Comment: How is 33 related to February? Is 33 supposed to represent the day of the year?

Comment: The first thing you'd need to figure out is how "33" means "February 2".  Once you define that translation logic, you can start to write code which performs that logic.  (Note: There exist date/time libraries which will probably be *very* helpful here, rather than writing your own.  Dates are *hard*.)

Comment: What is the output of `60`? `February 29` or `Mars 1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format your date and [`withDayOfYear(int dayOfYear)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfYear-int-) to set the 33th day of the year, as next:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d");
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().withDayOfYear(33).format(formatter));
```

or as proposed by @Tunaki

```
System.out.println(Year.now().atDay(33).format(formatter));
```

**Output:**

```
February 2
```

Comment: `Year.now().atDay(33)`, more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could assume a non-leap year and use the following:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] months = {"Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."};
        int[] daysinMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        int n = 33; // the input value
        int i = 0;

        n = n % 365;

        while (n > daysinMonth[i]) {
            n -= daysinMonth[i];
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(months[i] + " " + n);
    }
}
```